# Visual Basic connection to a database made in MySql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Hey guys I have a problem connecting to my database from my easyphpMyadmin
I get this error ( I use catch and try to collect the message) -
[image: code with error]
[image: PHP]

Thanks in advance

Imports MySql.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1

```
Dim dbCon As MySqlConnection
Dim strQuery As String = ""
Dim SQLCmd As MySqlCommand
Dim DR As MySqlDataReader



Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    GetDBData()

End Sub

Private Sub GetDBData()
    Try
        'PREPARE CONNECTION AND QUERY
        dbCon = New MySqlConnection("Server = localhost;Database = users; Uid=root; Pwd = password ")
        strQuery = "SELECT users.name, users.surname " & _
            "FROM users "

        SQLCmd = New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbCon)
        '  Pwd = password
        ' Open
        dbCon.Open()

        DR = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader

        While DR.Read
            txtData = txtData.Text & DR.Item("name") & Space(10) & DR.Item("surname") & vbCrLf
        End While

        'Close

        DR.Close()
        dbCon.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(" Failure to communicate " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: What if the imports don't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`txtData` is a TextBox. So to set its content you need to use the property Text.
Instead your code tries to assign the string resulting from the concatenation directly to a TextBox object that obviously cannot be assigned to a string.

```
 While DR.Read
        txtData.Text = txtData.Text & _
              DR.Item("name") & Space(10) & DR.Item("surname") & vbCrLf
 End While
```

Also remember to set the `Multiline` property of the `txtData` to true and be sure to increase the height of the textbox, otherwise you will not see the lines after the first one.

Comment: Oh my GOD, thanks a bunch. I haven't practiced in a while VB and my intermediate skills are really rusty, thanks a lot.